# Dynamically change the placeholder value

Tags: html, forms

The append below works but I would like to replace the text "Example" with the variable test:

```
var test = 10;
```

Need to replace the placeholder value dynamically
So the result should say 10 where I says Example today. How do I modify my append?

```
$('#edit_news_modal').find('.modal-body').append('<input class="form-control exampleclass" type="text" placeholder="Example" readonly>');
```

Comment: Instead of `Example` you can use `' + test + '`. So will see `10`, instead of `Example`. Have a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/dypdmKP?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I test with this: var test  = "This is a test";. I only see the test "This", why?

Comment: Hmm... Could you provide the code of your attempt? Use, for ex., codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or whatever.

Comment: " ' + test + ' " Changed to this and it worked. Thanks for the help! I appreciate it it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the `placeholder` attribute like this ( I added your test variable, but you can use any text):

`$(itemYouWantToUpdate).attr('placeholder', test);`